# quickblox crash on iPad not iPhone

Tags: ios, quickblox

I tried the chat example codes on 2 device using 2 different OS versions.
iPhone 6 plus(9.1) and iPad mini 1st Gen(8.4).
It works fine on the iPhone while it crashes on the iPad.

Code
(QMChatService.m [line 63])

```
if ([QBSession currentSession].currentUser != nil) [self loadCachedDialogsWithCompletion:nil];
```

Console log

```
2016-02-12 12:09:34.966 samplechat[3859:257361] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: acct)'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x24f94137 0x3370fc77 0x24eaf655 0x1421ef 0x1411ed 0x548e19 0x1410e9 0xcf5fb 0xe8323 0x513bf 0xe85c7 0x548187 0x548e19 0xe8559 0x4e8f5 0x285f474d 0x2869f4e5 0x2869f40d 0x2869e981 0x2869e6b7 0x2869e425 0x2869e3b9 0x285f1bbb 0x280073e5 0x28002c35 0x28002abd 0x2800245f 0x2800224f 0x28858195 0x28858f1d 0x288637a9 0x28857287 0x2ba3dec1 0x24f5a255 0x24f59519 0x24f57cb7 0x24ea39a1 0x24ea37b3 0x28659a57 0x28654635 0x5c165 0x33cddaaf)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

@edit
I tested on another iPad 2(9.2.1) and its working fine. I think there is a problem with the backwards compatibility.

Comment: Have you try with exception breakpoint? If you import Quickblokx with CocoaPods you can debug libraries.

Comment: I see the Quickblox framework in the sample-chat project, not in the Pods project. i did run the pods install command in that project root folder in terminal.

Comment: i'm getting this crash on an iphone with ios 8 as well.